# Command returns nothing

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm assuming its going wrong somewhere and on_command_error is catching it but not giving me any feedback about it...

I am pretty sure I did this correct as I copied it directly from another bot, but clearly I am missing something. I feel like I'm just missing some small detail.

```
@client.command(name='info')
@commands.has_any_role("Community Manager")
async def info(self, ctx):
        """Display bot info, e.g. library versions."""
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.description = ctx.bot.description
        ainfo = await ctx.bot.application_info()
        owner = str(ainfo.owner)
        embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner)
        embed.add_field(name="# of commands", value=len(ctx.bot.commands))
        num_guilds = len(ctx.bot.guilds)
        num_users = sum(not member.bot for member in ctx.bot.get_all_members())
        embed.add_field(name="Serving", value=f"{num_users} people in {num_guilds} guilds")
        embed.add_field(name="Python", value="{0}.{1}.{2}".format(*sys.version_info))
        embed.add_field(name="discord.py", value=discord.__version__)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Add a `raise Exception("did my code make it here?")` in between each line of code one at a time and once you stop seeing this exception raised, you'll know which line is blowing up.

Comment: Started doing it your way, no results, so I disabled on_command_error completely and found out that it didnt like `async def info(self, ctx):` removed the `self` and problem was resolved.

Comment: For the future, you should add a `raise error`, or some printing to the console, to the end of `on_command_error` so you can see them without removing the event.